# How do you call g++?

Tags: command-line, g++

I wanted to use `g++`. However, when I type in `g++` in the terminal, it says, "fatal error no input files". I have asked a similar question before but to avoid extending the discussion in the comments, i have asked this solely for `g++`. I would also like to know the type of files that are compiled .i.e the nature of the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ubuntu you can append `--help` onto most commands to see more information about how to run them. In this case:

```
$ g++ --help
Usage: g++ [options] file...
Options:
   ....
```

You can also look at `man g++` which will tell you *lots* more but here's the synopsis:

```
SYNOPSIS
       gcc [-c|-S|-E] [-std=standard]
           [-g] [-pg] [-Olevel]
           [-Wwarn...] [-Wpedantic]
           [-Idir...] [-Ldir...]
           [-Dmacro[=defn]...] [-Umacro]
           [-foption...] [-mmachine-option...]
           [-o outfile] [@file] infile...
```

The short of it is you need to provide a filename to your source file. Eg:

```
g++ test.cpp
```

Comment: g++ -v can also be useful :) It prints the version of this tool.

Comment: What type of file is it?

Comment: @user235315 Because you said you wanted to use `g++`, I inferred you have a C or C++ source file you want to compile... Because that's what `g++` is all about.

Comment: I understood that just now and ran the command  g++ main.cpp -o main,however it gave me:error: main.cpp: No such file or directory.Why did this happen?

Comment: If it's telling you that, there's no `main.cpp` on your current path. Make sure you `cd` into the right place before you run it. And remember the Linux command line is furiously case sensitive.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by cd.

Comment: `cd` is a shell command to change the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `.cpp` file, you can compile it with `g++` and then run the compiled file. For example:

```
g++ testfile.cpp -o testfile
```

(The `-o` option tells the compiler (`g++`) the executable output file's name. In fact, you can change the output filename to whatever you want apart from source file name.)

Then you can execute the compiled file with:

```
./testfile
```

Executable files are run using `./` from the same directory.

Comment: what exactly is the nature of this file that has to be compiled?Can it be a simple file in libre OfficeWriter?

Comment: @user235315 No, LibreOffice documents are not valid source code files. The file to be compiled has to be a plain text file, such as what Gedit would produce, containing valid C++ code.

Comment: As far as I know the file must have `*.cpp` extension CMIIW. Libre Office? I just try it, when I save with `.cpp` extension, the result is `examplecode.cpp.odt`

Comment: OK I put some code into Gedit, and named the file main.cpp, and then saved it. However when I ran the command g++ main.cpp -o main in the terminal it said: error: main.cpp: No such file or directory
What do i do now.

Comment: It because you run `g++` command in other directory instead of your `main.cpp` directory.
Did you use that command in your working directory? For example : you save your `main.cpp` file in `/home/user/main.cpp`, so you have to `cd /home/user/` then `g++ main.cpp -o main`.